# mvn deploy == (mvn install && mvn deploy:deploy)?

Tags: maven

I just saw this steps in a build job:

1. mvn install
2. check some of the built stuff without deleting anything...
3. mvn deploy -Dskip.all.possible.stuff.so

Couldn't the 3rd step be achieved by calling

```
mvn deploy:deploy
```

That is, does calling `install` and then `deploy:deploy` go through the exact same steps as just calling `deploy`?

**EDIT**:  from JFMeier's answer I found out the difference, `deploy:deploy` executes the `deploy` goal from the  `maven-deploy-plugin`, it doesn't execute all the goals attached to the `deploy` phase.

Comment: This is true as long as no other plugin was attached to the deploy phase, i.e. if the pom.xml defines additional goals for the deploy phase, these would be ignored if you just call `deploy:deploy`.

Comment: Right, that was the pitfall I was looking for. Please post as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true as long as no other plugin was attached to the deploy phase, i.e. if the pom.xml defines additional goals for the deploy phase, these would be ignored if you just call `deploy:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

If you call `mvn deploy`, you will implicitly call every phases of the maven lifecycle before the deploy phase. If you check [this table](http://www.codetab.org/wp-content/uploads/mvn-lifecycle-default.png), you will see that `deploy` comes just after `install` in the default lifecycle so if you call `mvn install` and then `mvn deploy:deploy` you will call all the phases from the beginning of the lifecycle and you could directly call `mvn deploy`as well.

Comment: As stated in the question, some stuff needs to be done after install but before deploying, so can't call deploy directly.

Comment: If I just quote the question: "That is, does calling install and then deploy:deploy go through the exact same steps as just calling deploy?". That's my answer.

Comment: But in fact, you're right: if you call deploy directly, you can't do nothing between install and deploy.

Comment: See the edit on on the question, there is indeed a difference